# $\sigma$-additivity inequality

Tags: measure-theory

I understand all the properties of $\sigma$-additive function $m$. However, I’m struggling to see where this inequality comes from.

There is a positive measure set $A$, an interval $I$ with $m(A\cap I)> \frac{8}{9}m(I)$ and a real number $x\in (-\frac{1}{9}m(I),\frac{1}{9}m(I))$. The inequality is

$$m[(A \cap I) \cap (x + (A\cap I))]\geq m(I) - 2 m(I\setminus A) - m[(I \cap (x+I)]$$